# How to use correctly ServiceStack IServiceGateway methods?

Tags: servicestack

`IServiceGateway` provides two main sync methods to call services.

```
void IServiceGateway.Publish(object requestDto)

T Send<T>(IReturn<T> request)
```

I understand that `Send()` allows me to consume the return type, whereas `Publish()` no.
Now imagine that `T` implements `IReturnVoid`, should I use `Publish()` or `Send()`?
What are the differences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Publish()` API should semantically be used for time-decoupled "One Way" operations like "Fire and Forget" requests.

How they're handled is up to the gateway implementation, e.g. in All Service Clients `Publish()` sends the Request DTO to ServiceStack's /oneway pre-defined endpoint which if an MQ was registered would publish it to the MQ instead of executing it, if no MQ is registered the behavior is the same as calling `Send()`, except that the successful response would be discarded.

Whilst it's typically used with `IReturnVoid` requests, they can also be used for normal requests, e.g. if a system supported creating system jobs with `CreateJob`, clients could call `Send()` if they wanted the job executed immediately and needed to wait until it was done or they could call `Publish()` to start long-running jobs they just wanted to queue to be executed in the background but didn't need to wait for the finished result.

Comment: Ok. So if I'm expecting a possible Exception I understand that it is better to call Send(), isn't it?

Comment: @labilbe If the client needs to act differently based on whether the request failed, yeah it should use `Send()`.